# Error sending Whatsapp using "Click to Chat"

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Previously my code already worked but recently when sending a message using "Click to Chat". When executing the script it opens a page of the message to send and when pressing "Send" the message is not sent and it opens the html code of the page.

As I mentioned before, the code already worked and nothing was modified. Does anyone else have this?

I did tests with the current and previous syntax, running directly in Chrome:

```
https://wa.me/5211234567890?text=Hi
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5211234567890&text=Hi
```

This opens in place of "WhatsApp Web":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" dir="ltr" loc="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>WhatsApp Web</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>

<meta name="description" content="Quickly send and receive WhatsApp messages right from your computer.">
<meta name="og:description" content="Quickly send and receive WhatsApp messages right from your computer."/>
<meta name="og:url" content="https://web.whatsapp.com/"/>
<meta name="og:title" content="WhatsApp Web"/>
<meta name="og:image" content="https://www.whatsapp.com/img/whatsapp-promo.png"/>

<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon/1x/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="https://whatsapp.net/favicon_web.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="194x194" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" type="image/png" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cssm_99362fa8365d8e39028c84edca18e758.css">

<style>
html, body, #app {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page `https://web.whatsapp.com/send` has a bug and loads the last html version of the home of `https://web.whatsapp.com`, so the index of the page doesn't even load any process and returns only the last html version of the send page. The bug could be fixed in the next updates of `WhatsApp Web`, if not then contact WhatsApp and tell them.
Here: [WhatsApp Web / Contact](http://mailto:webclient_web@support.whatsapp.com)

Comment: No problem. Solved very fast!

Comment: @MoisésPérez how dod you fix it? I'm still getting the issue

Comment: Hi, apparently it was a bug of WhatsApp Web.